# Infinite scrolling jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jquery ,ajax and php to implementing infinite scrolling 
the image from database

and the code  just works one time when i reach the end of a page and show me the message "No More Content" when there is actually content in the database

here is my cod

index.php

```
<html >
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/db.php'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM photo ORDER by PhotoNo DESC limit 12";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$actual_row_count =mysql_num_rows($result);
 ?>
<head>
   <title>Infinite Scroll</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var page = 1;


        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#more').hide();
            $('#no-more').hide();

            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
                $('#more').css("top","400");
                $('#more').show();
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

                $('#more').hide();
                $('#no-more').hide();

                page++;

                var data = {
                    page_num: page
                };

                var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";

                if((page-1)* 12 > actual_count){
                    $('#no-more').css("top","400");
                    $('#no-more').show();
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "data.php",
                        data:data,
                        success: function(res) {
                            $("#result").append(res);
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }


        });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id='more' >Loading More Content</div>
    <div id='no-more' >No More Content</div>
    <div id='result'>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rest_logo=$row['PhotoName'];
        $image="../images/rest/".$rest_logo;
            echo '<div><img src='.$image.' /></div>';
        }
        ?>
        </div>







</body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php

$requested_page = $_POST['page_num'];
$set_limit = (($requested_page - 1) * 12) . ",12";


include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/db.php'); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo ORDER by PhotoNo DESC limit $set_limit");



$html = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$rest_logo=$row['PhotoName'];
$image="../images/rest/".$rest_logo;
$html .= '<div><img src='.$image.' /></div>';
}


echo $html;
exit;
?>
```

I really nead a help

Comment: Take a look at [**MySQL's OFFSET**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: in limit you can specify two arguments, i.e. (from where , upto what limit)

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but don't use `mysql_` functions anymore. They are deprecated. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)** or **[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php)** instead.

Comment: @Ameer how i would do that and which limit in index.php or data.php

Comment: Change `var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";` to `var actual_count = <?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>;`. You need an integer, not a string.

Comment: you get your actual_count by setting a limit of 12. so your result is always 12 if you have more than one site. That cannot be correct. Remove the limit 12 in your first query.

Comment: @steven I think you don't get the point here. If you just remove the limit in the first query, all the photos will be displayed at once. Which is really bad when you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

You see to be setting the variables wrong from a quick look:

```
var actual_count = "<?php echo $actual_row_count; ?>";
```

You're using mysql_num_rows() to count the return on your first set of results. But that is limited to 12.

You need to do a second mysql query to get all the images without limi, then count them to get the total number of images in the database.

Comment: Note that the double quotes shouldn't be there.

Comment: +1 but i think he doesnt need a second query. Just remove the limit 12 from the first... Oh sorry, forget it! you are right.. he used the first query later.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM photo` would be quicker than `SELECT * FROM photo` and then count the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php your query is only returning 12 rows meaning that $actual_row_count is only ever going to be 12. Instead I would set $actual_row_count to the result of the query "SELECT count
(*) FROM photo".

My personal preference for these sort of things is to return a JSON response which only contains the n responses that are loading and have a template html stored in javascript. The way you've written it will return all the photo's on the last query instead of the last 12 that you want.